# A SIP provider with PSTN number and extension range for DID

Tags: twilio, sip

I have a Twilio account with USA PSTN number like +11234567890. In my company all users have an internal SIP 4-digit number like 2001, 2002 etc.

Is somewhere a USA SIP provider which allows anyone USA client to call my number +11234567890 with extension directly, like +11234567890XXXX, and pass this full number into my PBX via SIP trunk call? With that number I can bridge a caller and callee directly (Direct Inward Call, DID), bypassing voice menu.

A Twilio techsupport says that i must buy another PSTN number, and they don't allowing such extensions. So, buying a external number per every user looks silly.

Comment: Have you considered that people don't dial phones like that? Even if this is possible you might not get a lot of people using.  Could be chasing a edge case.  Sorry couldn't help with your technical question.

Comment: This is off topic. And not possible anyway, as the telecoms network will discard the digits following the real number.

Answer (score 2):

> Is somewhere a USA SIP provider which allows anyone USA client to call my number +11234567890 with extension directly, like +11234567890XXXX, and pass this full number into my PBX via SIP trunk call?

No. This is impossible -- phone numbers in the US (as well as Canada and some countries in the Caribbean) must confirm to the [North American Numbering Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan), which mandates that phone numbers be nine digits long. The US telephone network does not permit longer numbers to be dialed, no more than an IPv4 network would permit a five-octet IP address to be used.

Some devices will allow extra digits to be entered, e.g. to allow novelty "phonewords" to be dialed, but the extra digits are discarded. They are not sent to the phone network.

Answer (score 1):

As George mentions in the comment , that is not the most intuitive way of dialing for the end users. You could achieve something similar with your Twilio number by using inbound PSTN or SIP call to invoke your application which can ask for extension and respond using the [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) noun of the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb, to establish a call with your SIP endpoint.

A possible flow to achieve what you require is mentioned below :

1. Create a rest endpoint that does the following

   - Asks caller to enter extension number by [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say)-ing a message
   - Uses TwiML to [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) extension number from caller
   - `<Dial>` this extension on your sip infrastructure
2. Point your Twilio Number to above endpoint.

3 . Dont forget to [whitelist](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/receiving-sip-how-it-works#advanced-features) Twilio's SIP address and media ports in your infrastructure

Sample TwiML to dial to your sip infrastructure is mentioned below (if extension is can be dialed directly as endpoint , do a direct sip to the extension   , else pass extension as a header to your pbx and have pbx dial the extension)

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Sip>
            sip:stan@example.com?extensionNumber=2001&customeheader=xyz
        </Sip>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```